# If someone would have obtained two MSc degrees from the same university, how do you put that on a business card?

Tags: degree, business-card

If someone would have obtained two MSc degrees from the same university for example MSc politics from UCL and MSc international relations from UCL too, how do you put that on a business card?

Comment: It would be helpful to know in which country you will be using the business cards.

Comment: Why would you put more than one on there if it´s the same degree (MSc)?

Comment: Why would you put anything about your degrees on your business card?

Comment: @JeffE Espcially when it is a master's degree. If it was an MD or something, that is one thing. But listing a MSc. seems a bit tacky IMO.

Comment: @JeffE: There are countries and businesses where this is the norm and expected. Please do not assume that because this is not the norm in US Academia, it is not the norm anywhere.

Comment: @Vladhagen: See comment for JeffE.

Comment: @user111388 Please do not assume bad faith.

Comment: @JeffE: I don't.

Answer (score 2):

This will very likely depend on the laws of the country you are in and the norms of the business you are in (does it look complete or pretentious to list all degrees). For example, in Austria you would/could just list all titles (except if you work in an especially "young" company where you would probably not list degrees at all).

Since you seem to emphasize "from the same university", could you mabe explain why this could make a difference to "two master titles from different universities"?

Comment: Since JeffE asks in a comment why one would want to put degrees on a business card, let me say that there are countries and businesses where this is the norm and expected. Please do not assume that because this is not the norm in US Academia, it is not the norm anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is up to you, but it is good to follow the customs and culture of the country and the workplace.

E.g. many universities and government positions will try to list all your titles, both of the respect to you, but also to give a better representation of the person in mind.

Many companies would also want to show that they have highly-skilled workers to their customers/partners. It is interesting to note that (at least from my experience) most companies will only include one (usually the top one) title. This is mainly done not to look too pretentious, but also to make it easier for any person who would read your business card to understand your general position without having to take a minute or two understanding how all the titles line up.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers question why you want to include all your academic qualifications on a business card. Whether or not to do so, is very much a matter of local custom and practice. Only you, seeking advice **locally** if you wish, can decide whether you should do so.

If you want to include them then the answer is clear: you are  John Doe, MSc(Somewhere), MSc(Somewhere). Such a formulation might give rise to questions, but so what? You have a good story to tell.

You might like to check what the relevant university's exact title for your degrees is: are they both actually MSc? The exact abbreviation might differ. One of mine is in fact MMath, and another is in fact MSc, but the previous year's class got MSc(Eng).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by MSc(Somewhere)? Do people in some countries really write (or have to write) e.g. MSc(University of Riga) as their degree? That seems tacky to me (but to each their own, of course).

Comment: The official title of my MMath degree is MMath(Cantab.). Cantab being an abbreviation of the Latin name of Cambridge, England. My MSc is from London University, and hence I would write, formally, MSc(Lond.). Tacky or not, that is how it is, and I would argue that it is practical too. If you see that someone claims to have some qualification then you often wish to know where they obtained it.

Comment: The idea that people want to know/to tell where they obtained their degree is a part of US/UK culture which is very hard for continental europeans to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply but a couple of points of possible interest:

1. Usually it's an M.A. rather than an M.Sc. in fields like politics or international relations. But obviously this depends on the universities and departments in question - it may be an A.M., M.Phil., etc. Now if the two universities/departments have different designations, that may be one possible solution.

For example, J.R. Ewing    *M.A. (Politics), M.Phil. (Int. Rels.).*

2. What's so bad about having double master's degrees ? Especially when the field is somewhat different.

Thus: J.F. Kennedy Jr.     *M.A. (Politics), M.A. (Int. Rels.).*